# highchart - scatter : set decimals of x-axis and y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, decimal, scatter-plot

Part I

I want to fix decimals of the x-axis and y-axis elements in the scatter-plot (highcharts).
I've searched documentation in highcharts about properties of scatter-plot. But, I've found nothing. I want to set 2 decimals of elements in x-axis and y-axis because I have a very large number with 8 decimals o more.

Part II

Well, It works the decimals. However, the element of x-axis and y-axis have the same value now. Is it possible to fix this?. I would like the difference between each element of axis equals 0.1. I mean 34.66, 34.67, 34.68, 34.69

[Part II -This is the new problem now](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6rD9LsvglEAdnREcHYwc2hwUXM/edit)

[Part I - You can see the picture. This is the problem](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6rD9LsvglEAaHZVeHNhanJVcmc/edit)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please share whatever code you have till now to increase your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [formatter function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) with `.toFixed(2)`. Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/).

Comment: I found another solution. In formatter function with Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2);